# Java Script redirect is not working in smarty .tpl file

Tags: javascript, redirect, smarty, window.location

I am developing a web application using PHP, Smarty combination, I have wrote a javascript redirect in the .tpl file, but it is not working now. Please take a look at the code and help me to find out the problem.

This is the code segment,

```
{literal}

<script type="text/javascript">
    if(confirm({/literal}'{$info}'{literal})){
        window.location = "logbook_client_section.php?e={$ckey}";
    }
</script>
{/literal}
```

Problem is only in the redirect section, it is now redirecting to `logbook_client_section_add.php?e={$ckey}` , I would like to get the value of `$ckey ( smarty variable)` in the url.

Comment: check that you have $template->assign('ckey', $ckey); in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a `{$var}` inside a `{literal}` block. That cannot work...

The cleanest solution to avoid unreadable code caused by closing/opening the `{literal}` blocks within your code would be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var info = '{$info}';
    var ckey = '{$ckey}';
{literal}
    if(confirm(info)){
        window.location = "logbook_client_section.php?e=" + ckey;
    }
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks . Solved . Great Support.

Answer (score 3):

try it

```
  {literal}

     <script type="text/javascript">
         if(confirm('{/literal}{$info}{literal}')){
             window.location = "oop.php?e={/literal}{$ckey}{literal}";
         }
     </script>
     {/literal}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this instead:

```
var ckey='{$ckey}';
window.location = "logbook_client_section.php?e="+ckey;
```